# How is a funnel operation process of Amplitude analytics?

Tags: analytics, custom-events, amplitude-analytics

I'm working on mobile app service company. 
My job is to handle data of the app.

I'm trying to analyze the app data through 'Amplitude analytics(AT)' 
Custom event tracking by AT works pretty well. 
I'm satisfied with this function of AT.

However, there is problem in funnel function of AT/
For example, there are 4 custom events(called A,B,C,D) which are I installed.
Event A,B,C is related to each other, like after event A occur, user can take event B or C. 
Event D is not related to event A,B,C.
My question is this.
When I try to figure out the event A to B conversing rate by funnel function of AT, there is no problem. 
Because event A and B is related.

However even I put the event A as 1st step and D as 2nd step, funnel show the result and the result(conversion rate) is not zero.
Users can not occur event D after event A.

I don't understand the funnel operation process of AT.
If somebody know the answer, please help me.

Thax.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself.

Even event A and D looks there is no relation, It could happen.

If there is really no relation between A and D,

Funnel conversion can not happen and has shown

because Funnel in Amplitude is closed funnel.

I ask it to Amplitude vendor of the South Korea.

Wish it help you.